# Get contents of passing string from a script

Tags: shell-script, string, eval

I would like to get, in the output, the content of `KW0_TEXT` and `KW1_TEXT` from the "for" of this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
STRS=" KW0 KW1 "
KW0_TEXT="text text text"
KW1_TEXT="text text  text text"
for str in ${STRS}; do
echo ${str}_TEXT
eval echo ${str}_TEXT
done
```

so far, in the output, I got only:

```
KW0_TEXT
KW0_TEXT
KW1_TEXT
KW1_TEXT
```

Comment: The reason `eval echo $var` isn't working as you expect is because the variable gets expanded first, before eval gets a change to execute. There are tricks you can do to make eval work, but the answers hold better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your /bin/sh is actually /bin/bash, you can use variable indirection:

```
#!/bin/bash
STRS=" KW0 KW1 "
KW0_TEXT="text text text"
KW1_TEXT="text text  text text"
for str in ${STRS}; do
  var=${str}_TEXT
  printf "%s\n" "${!var}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If your /bin/sh is actually /bin/bash, and your version is fairly recent, you can use an associative array

```
#!/bin/bash
strs=( KW0 KW1 )
declare -A text=( 
    [KW0]="text text text" 
    [KW1]="text text  text text" 
)
for str in "${strs[@]}"; do 
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$str" "${text[$str]}"
done
```

```
KW0     text text text
KW1     text text  text text
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're missing a literal `$` in your `eval` use. After the variable is substituted, the command you're evaluating is

```
echo KW0_TEXT
```

but you want

```
echo $KW0_TEXT
```

It should be:

```
eval echo '$'${str}_TEXT
```

However, the indirect variable method of Jeff Schaller is preferable if you're using a shell that supports it.